# Typo3 6.2.x sys_category renderMode

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

We are using a Typo3 6.2.9 with the tx_news extension (3.1.0) with a bunch of sys_category objects.

In FrontEnd every article has a link to its "primary" category page - which means we make a link to the category news page using newsItem.categories.0.uid in the template.

I know that sorting is supported because I manually exchanged the sorting values of two sys_category_record_mm entries of an article.

`update sys_category_record_mm set sorting_foreign=<sortingvalue1> where uid_local = <sys_category_uid2> and uid_foreign = <tx_news_domain_model_news_uid>;
update sys_category_record_mm set sorting_foreign=<sortingvalue2> where uid_local = <sys_category_uid1> and uid_foreign = <tx_news_domain_model_news_uid>;`

I also know that the following line in the pageconfig of my root-page disables the category field:
`TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news.categories.disabled = 1`

Therefore I know that

```
TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news.categories
```

adresses the correct field.

Now I would like to change the renderMode of the categories field for news items. The default renderMode "tree" does not support sorting of the categories. 
[image]

Thats why I'd like to change it to the one the was used in older Typo3 versions, the one that is still used with tags.
[image]

I tried:

```
TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news {
categories{

        select >
        group >
        check >
        group {
             size = 5
             autoSizeMax = 10 
             max_size = 10 
             show_thumbs = 0 
             maxitems = 100 
             minitems = 0 
             disable_controls = 0
        }
}
```

and

```
TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news {
categories{

        config.select.renderMode = singlebox
}
```

and

```
TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news {
categories{

        config.renderMode = singlebox
}
```

and other variations there upon.

Has anyone an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot sort categories within the selection tree.

But you can sort them.
Just got to the page/folder where you created the categories - be sure to be on list module - and there you have the sorting buttons.

[image: list module - data storage - see the order]
*list module - data storage - see the order*

[image: category selection tree - compare with the order above]
*category selection tree - compare with the order above*